# Как вывести данные с API на страницу

Tags: javascript, api

Хотелось бы научиться выводить на страницу данные с API.
Есть API: http://opendata.trudvsem.ru/api/v1/vacancies
Используя API портала "Работа в России", мне не удается вывести на страницу название вакансии, название компании, телефон, размер заработной платы. Подозреваю, что я неправильно пишу данную строчку: data.vacancies.vacancy[0] ["name"];

```
fetch(`http://opendata.trudvsem.ru/api/v1/vacancies`)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) { 
            console.log(data);

        document.querySelector(".person").textContent = data.vacancies.vacancy[0] ["name"];
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Fetch Error", err);
        });
```

Comment: Попробуйте так `data.results.vacancies[0].vacancy["job-name"]`. Смотрите внимательнее какой объект возвращает запрос

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось!